# ReactJs: PrivateRoute component gets called twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I have this privateRoute component that I use to manage authentication:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => {
  // This gets logged twice when I navigate in the app
  // Using history.push("/url")
  // And gets logged once when I type the url and hit enter on the browser
  console.log(
    "===============INSIDE PrivateRoute Component========================"
  );
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        auth.isAuthenticated === true ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

The strange thing is that this component gets logged twice when I navigate in the app. For example, when I hit a button that triggers this code:

```
this.props.history.push("/edit-page-after-login");
```

And I have this in App.js:

```
    <PrivateRoute
      path="/edit-page-after-login"
      component={EditProfileAfterLogin}
    />
```

And I have a component that gets rendered in that route:

```
export default class EditProfileInSettings extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(
      " ~ file: EditProfileInSettings.js ~ line 5 ~ EditProfileInSettings ~ componentDidMount ~ componentDidMount"
    );
  }
  render() {
    return <div>Test</div>;
  }
}
```

So when I navigate to that component using `history.push`, this gets logged:

> ===============INSIDE PrivateRoute Component========================
>  ~ file: EditProfileInSettings.js ~ line 5 ~ EditProfileInSettings ~
> componentDidMount ~ componentDidMount
> ===============INSIDE PrivateRoute Component========================

For some strange reason, PrivateRoute component gets called **TWICE** which is causing me some issues in the logic I am trying to implement.

But, when I write the url in the browser and enter, it behaves correctly and it only gets called **ONCE**:

> ===============INSIDE PrivateRoute Component========================
>  ~ file: EditProfileInSettings.js ~ line 5 ~ EditProfileInSettings ~
> componentDidMount ~ componentDidMount

Any idea what's going on here?

---

**EDIT 1:** I have noticed this error only occurs when I do an API call to the backend inside the component:

```
class PrivateRouteTestComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("PrivateRouteTestComponent.componentDidMount is called!");
    // If I comment this out, the problem will not occur.
    // It only occurs with this line
    // It does an API call to the backend to get user profile
    this.props.getAuthenticatedUserProfile();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.props.history.push("/videos-page");
          }}
        >
          Home
        </button>
        <h6>Private route test component</h6>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT 2:** I finally found why this error occurs. Calling a function that dispatches something to the store will update the `PrivateRoute` so it will get called again:

```
class PrivateRouteTestComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("PrivateRouteTestComponent.componentDidMount is called!");
    // This doesn't cause the problem
    testBackendCall();
    // This causes the problem
    // Because it dispatches an action to the store
    // So PrivateRoute gets updated
    this.props.testBackendCallThatDispatchesSomethingToTheStore();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.props.history.push("/videos-page");
          }}
        >
          Home
        </button>
        <h6>Private route test component</h6>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What about https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route ``exact`` part??

Comment: I know that. But I don't see what it has to do with anything that I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing functional components and React class-based components, and expect that the logging in `PrivateRoute` and the one in `EditProfileInSettings` to be done at the same moment in the rendering cycle - but it's not.

In `EditProfileInSettings`, you log *on the mounting phase* (`componentDidMount`), which happens once in a component's rendering (if not unmounted).

In `PrivateRoute`, you log *on the rendering phase* (think the equivalent of `render` on a class `Component`), which happens every time React needs to update your component because of its props being changed.

If you want the two logging to be equivalent, either place your logging in a `useEffect()` on your `PrivateRoute`, or place your logging at the `render()` on your `EditProfileInSettings`.

---

Then, to know why your functional component is rendered two times, log all your props and spot the differences between two cycles.

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved my problem. Using React hooks to execute code in functional component only when it's mounted.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // EXECUTE THE CODE ONLY ONCE WHEN COMPONENT IS MOUNTED
  }, []);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        auth.isAuthenticated === true ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```